# jquery upload file ajax: can't make it work

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to upload a file, but can't get anything... Here is my html:

```
<form id=\"captimg\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"captureimg\">
                            <input type=\"text\" name=\"form_titre_photo_capture_mobile\" placeholder=\"Titre\" class=\"texte_texte_photo_capture_mobile\" id=\"form_titre_photo_capture_mobile\">
                            <input type=\"file\" capture=\"camera\" accept=\"image/*\" id=\"takePictureField\" name=\"takePictureField\">
                            </form>
<div class=\"loader\" id=\"spinner_m\">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                            <button id=\"FormSubmitPhotoCaptureMobile\" class=\"submit_button\">Envoyer</button>
```

And my jquery ajax:

```
$("#FormSubmitPhotoCaptureMobile").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if($("#form_titre_photo_capture_mobile").val()==="")
        {
            alert("Veuillez saisir un titre");
            return false;
        }
        $('#FormSubmitPhotoCaptureMobile').hide();
        $('#spinner_m').show();
            var form_data = new FormData($("#captimg"));                 
            form_data.append("file", takePictureField.files[0]);            
            form_data.append("titre", $("#form_titre_photo_capture_mobile").val());

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
            url: "captureimg",
            data:form_data,
            success:function(response){
            $('#bar').val(100);
            $("#responds").before(response);
            $("#form_titre_photo_capture_mobile").val('');
                        $('#spinner_m').hide();
                        $('#FormSubmitPhotoCaptureMobile').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

I've found tons of code and nothing is working... What's wrong in this one please?
Thanks

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: no, nothing... And I can get the text field in print_r($_POST) but nothing about the file...

Answer (score 0):

I just removed all slashes in your html and changed ajax url to `captureimg.php`.
On server side I'm dumped `$_FILES` and received this:

```
Array
(
[file] => Array
    (
        [name] => apache_pb2.png
        [type] => image/png
        [tmp_name] => home/tmp/phpA772.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 1463
    )
```

)

All works fine in Chrome. But in Firefox I'm get this error `TypeError: Value does not implement interface HTMLFormElement. var form_data = new FormData($("#captimg"));`

Comment: I'm trying to get the picture in canvas format then upload the text then convert it to picture. But can't get it for the moment :-(

Comment: I read somewhere what FormData is supported not all browsers. Why You not try to use some plugin for jquery?

Comment: Because I'm not advanced in javascript, and all plugins I checked are some big and complex scripts I can't adapt to my fits...

Comment: Maybe You will want try [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) - very simple and free plugin

Comment: uploadify: not free in html5!